# Calling doget on submit type of post and vice versa

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

While submitting a form on jsp, we define method type:-

1.) when it is Get---> doGet of servlet  is called.

2.) when it is Post---> doPost of servlet is called.

Is there a way thorough which i can achieve below scenario:-

1.) when it is Get---> doPost of servlet  is called.

2.) when it is Post---> doGet of servlet is called.

It was asked in my last interview, and i was not able to answer.
Possible solution which i gave was to call a doPost method inside doGet method and vice-versa, but in that case also method called will be same.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to override the [HttpServlet.service](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) method and call the methods as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You have described the default behaviour of the service method, as described in the [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) Javadoc (emphasis added) as

> Provides an abstract class to be subclassed to create an HTTP servlet suitable for a Web site. A subclass of `HttpServlet` must override at least one method, usually one of these:
>
> - `doGet`, if the servlet supports HTTP GET requests
> - `doPost`, for HTTP POST requests
> - `doPut`, for HTTP PUT requests
> - `doDelete`, for HTTP DELETE requests
> - `init` and `destroy`, to manage resources that are held for the life of the servlet
> - `getServletInfo`, which the servlet uses to provide information about itself
>
> There's almost no reason to override the service method. service handles standard HTTP requests by dispatching them to the handler methods for each HTTP request type (**the doXXX methods listed above**).

For your specific example, you *could* override the method.